# How to collect a map of a pojo id to a set of a property of a collection on the pojo

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use streams to get a map of a pojo to a Set of items exposed by a property on the pojo.  I realise that isn't clear so I'll show how I've done it without streams.

I have and enum of product categories, and enum of Products and a list of shops with the product like this

```
public enum Category {
    FRUIT, VEGITABLE, MEAT;
}

public enum Product {
    APPLE ( Category.FRUIT ),
    PEAR ( Category.FRUIT ),
    BANANA ( Category.FRUIT ),
    CARROT ( Category.VEGITABLE ),
    POTATO ( Category.VEGITABLE ),
    CABBAGE ( Category.VEGITABLE ),
    MINCE ( Category.MEAT ),
    CHOP ( Category.MEAT ),
    STEAK ( Category.MEAT );

    private final Category category;

    Product( Category category ) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static Product fromValue( String v ) {
        return valueOf( v );
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }
}

public class Shop {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private EnumSet<Product> products;

    public Shop( long id, String name, Collection<Product> products ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.products = ofNullable( products ).map( EnumSet::copyOf ).orElse( null );
    }
}
```

I have made a method which creates some dummy data...

```
public static List<Shop> getListOfShops() {
        Shop shop1 = new Shop( 1, "Green Grocer", EnumSet.of( Product.APPLE, Product.BANANA, Product.CARROT, Product.CABBAGE ) );
        Shop shop2 = new Shop( 2, "Supermarket", EnumSet.of( Product.APPLE, Product.BANANA
            , Product.CARROT, Product.CABBAGE, Product.CHOP, Product.MINCE ) );
        Shop shop3 = new Shop( 3, "Butcher", EnumSet.of( Product.STEAK ) );

        return Arrays.asList( shop1, shop2, shop3 );
    }
```

I want to create a map of shop categories

```
Map<String, EnumSet<Category>> shopCategories = new HashMap<>();
```

which will have contents like this

> {Butcher=[MEAT], Supermarket=[FRUIT, VEGITABLE, MEAT], Green
> Grocer=[FRUIT, VEGITABLE]}

I have achieved this with some basic loops which I was hoping I was smart enough to convert into streams

```
public static Map<String, EnumSet<Category>> getCategories( List<Shop> shops ) {

    Map<String, EnumSet<Category>> shopCategories = new HashMap<>();

    for ( Shop s : shops ) {
        Set<Category> cats = new HashSet<Category>();
        for ( Product p : s.getProducts() ) {
            cats.add( p.getCategory() );
        }
        shopCategories.put ( s.getName(), EnumSet.copyOf (cats) );
    }

    return shopCategories;
}
```

I have a vague idea how to convert it to a map of shop to products with a collector as the terminal operation.  Something along the lines of

```
shops.stream().collect( Collectors.toMap ( s -> s::getName ,
    PaymentProductWithCapabilities::getProducts ) );
```

I'm struggling for an entry point into understanding how to proceed to mapping the Categories instead ?  Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform the products of the shop you are streaming on, into the value of the expected `Map`using the `valueMapper` in `Collectors.toMap`, similar to your iterative style as:

```
return shops.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Shop::getName,
                s -> EnumSet.copyOf(s.getProducts().stream()
                        .map(Product::getCategory)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet()))));
```

To be precise, your implementation overrides the value of the `Map`, if the same `name` is found for two shops, which in the `Collectors.toMap` can be implemented with the merge function such as `(a,b) -> b`.

Or better as suggested by [Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161878/gene) in a [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305418/how-to-collect-a-map-of-a-pojo-id-to-a-set-of-a-property-of-a-collection-on-the/63305689#comment111942900_63305689):

```
return shops.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Shop::getName,
                s -> s.getProducts().stream()
                        .map(Product::getCategory)
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
                                () -> EnumSet.noneOf(Category.class))),
                (a, b) -> b));
```

Answer (score 1):

Same can be achieved using `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.flatMapping` as -

```
Map<String, EnumSet<Category>> categories =
        shops.stream()
            .collect(
                groupingBy(
                    Shop::getName,
                    flatMapping(
                        s -> s.getProducts().stream().map(Product::getCategory),
                        toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(Category.class)))));
```

`Collectors.groupingBy` groups stream based on `Shop::getName` and `Collectors.flatMapping`flattens List of Products and `map` maps product to the `Product` category. `Collectors.flatMapping` also `Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream` which can be used to collect `EnumSet<Category>`.